# Python Round Dataframe Columns with Specific Value If Exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

My input dataframe;

```
A       B 
0.3     0.6
0.4     3.05
1.6     4.35
0.15    5.47
4.19    9.99
```

I want to round my dataframe columns according to a specifi value if exists. My code is like below;

```
rounding=0.25

df['A']=round(df['A'] - rounding + 0.5)
df['B']=round(df['B'] - rounding + 0.5)
```

Output is;

```
A    B
1    1
1    3
2    5
0    6
4    10
```

The issue is if there is no "rounding" variable, it should be run automatically as default (0.5).
I need a code that can run for both together. Something like this or different;

```
if rounding==rounding:
    df['A']=round(df['A'] - rounding + 0.5)

else:
    df['A']=round(df['A'])
```

I saw many topics about rounding with specific value but i couldn' t see for this.

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: `the issue is if there is no "rounding" variable` - how possible? Can you explain more?

Comment: "rounding" variable may or may not. if there is no exist, it should accept as default round value which is 0.5

Comment: ya, but how is possible not exist? It is not clear for me.

Comment: the rounding value comes from another dataset. may not have for every customer.

Comment: @Salih if the rounding value is different for different rows, than it should be a column in the dataframe, not a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you think missing values - then replace it to `0` or another scalar  with `if-else` statement:

```
rounding = np.nan

rounding = 0 if rounding != rounding else rounding
print (rounding)
0
```

Or:

```
rounding = 0 if pd.isna(rounding) else rounding
print (rounding)
0
```

If exist value (not missing value):

```
rounding = 0.25

rounding = 0 if rounding != rounding else rounding
print (rounding)
0.25
```

---

```
df['A']=round(df['A'] - rounding + 0.5)
df['B']=round(df['B'] - rounding + 0.5)
print (df)
     A     B
0  1.0   1.0
1  1.0   4.0
2  2.0   5.0
3  1.0   6.0
4  5.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you will have a column in your `dataframe` with the "rounding" for each observation (a column you should achieve by merging data from another `dataframe`), you can simply do:

```
df['A'] = (df['A'] - df['rounding'].fillna(0.5) + 0.5).round(0)
df['B'] = (df['B'] - df['rounding'].fillna(0.5) + 0.5).round(0)
```